# java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView ERROR

Tags: android, eclipse, classcastexception

I am getting a ClassCastException error. I don't know why.
Tried to clean my project, but nothing happened.
Thanks in advance!

**logcat:**

```
04-30 18:03:44.122: W/dalvikvm(276): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
04-30 18:03:44.142: E/AndroidRuntime(276): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-30 18:03:44.142: E/AndroidRuntime(276): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.letsplay.gamster/com.letsplay.gamster.TutorialOne}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView
04-30 18:03:44.142: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
04-30 18:03:44.142: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-30 18:03:44.142: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-30 18:03:44.142: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-30 18:03:44.142: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-30 18:03:44.142: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-30 18:03:44.142: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-30 18:03:44.142: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-30 18:03:44.142: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-30 18:03:44.142: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-30 18:03:44.142: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-30 18:03:44.142: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-30 18:03:44.142: E/AndroidRuntime(276): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView
04-30 18:03:44.142: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at com.letsplay.gamster.TutorialOne.onCreate(TutorialOne.java:28)
04-30 18:03:44.142: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-30 18:03:44.142: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
04-30 18:03:44.142: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  ... 11 more
04-30 18:03:44.172: W/ActivityManager(59):   Force finishing activity com.letsplay.gamster/.TutorialOne
04-30 18:03:44.182: W/ActivityManager(59):   Force finishing activity com.letsplay.gamster/.menu
04-30 18:03:44.651: I/ARMAssembler(59): generated scanline__00000077:03515104_00000000_00000000 [ 33 ipp] (47 ins) at [0x315a58:0x315b14] in 398622 ns
04-30 18:03:44.681: W/ActivityManager(59): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{45071338 com.letsplay.gamster/.TutorialOne}
04-30 18:03:45.791: I/Process(276): Sending signal. PID: 276 SIG: 9
04-30 18:03:45.811: I/ActivityManager(59): Process com.letsplay.gamster (pid 276) has died.
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
**java:**

```
 package com.letsplay.gamster;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TutorialOne extends Activity implements OnCheckedChangeListener {

    TextView textOut;
    EditText textIn;
    RadioGroup radioG, styleG;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tutorial1);
        textOut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textChanges);
        textIn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        radioG = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.textGravity);
        radioG.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

        styleG = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.textStyle);
        styleG.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

        Button ok1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonOK);
        ok1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()  {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                textOut.setText(textIn.getText());

            }
        });
    }

    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(checkedId){
        case R.id.radioLeft:
            textOut.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
            break;
        case R.id.radioCenter:
            textOut.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            break;
        case R.id.radioRight:
            textOut.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
            break;
        case R.id.radioNormal:
            textOut.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.NORMAL), Typeface.NORMAL);
        break;
        case R.id.radioBold:
            textOut.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.BOLD), Typeface.BOLD);
        break;
        case R.id.radioItalic:
            textOut.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.ITALIC), Typeface.ITALIC);
        break;
        }

    }

}
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////**xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText android:text="" android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />



    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:weightSum="2">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/textStyle" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center" android:text="Style" android:textStyle="bold" />


        <TextView android:id="@+id/textGravity" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center" android:text="Gravity" android:textStyle="bold" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <RadioGroup android:id="@+id/radioStyle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:orientation="vertical">


            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radioNormal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Normal" />

            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radioItalic"
                android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Italic" />

            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radioBold"
                android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Bold" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <RadioGroup android:id="@+id/radioGravity"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:orientation="vertical">

            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radioLeft"
                android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Left" />

            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radioCenter"
                android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Center" />

            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radioRight"
                android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Right" />
        </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textChanges" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Введите текст" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/buttonOK" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="OK" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Check your xml for TutorialOne and make sure "android:id=textChanges" is a `TextView` also pls post the xml

Comment: Show us your XML layout

Comment: `textOut` is not declared as a TextView in layout.xml

Comment: Be sure that textOut, if it is indeed in the layout as a TextView is part of the tutorial1 layout and not some other layout.  You can only access UI components from the current layout.

Answer (score 0):

have you liked the classs in Androidmenifest.xml file, statements like this

```
<activity
android:name="com.example1.test.Splash"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```